# VAqua v7 lib causing Java application to fail

Tags: java, look-and-feel, macos-darkmode, aqua

Im was trying out the [VAqua Look and Feel](https://violetlib.org/vaqua/overview.html) on MacOS Catalina, its included in classpath and I call it like this

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel("org.violetlib.aqua.AquaLookAndFeel");
```

but then my code fails with

```
4/11/2019 13.16.22:GMT:UncaughtExceptionHandler:uncaughtException:SEVERE: An unexpected error has occurred com.apple.laf.ScreenMenu.addMenuListeners(Lcom/apple/laf/ScreenMenu;J)J on thread main, please report to support @jthink.net
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.apple.laf.ScreenMenu.addMenuListeners(Lcom/apple/laf/ScreenMenu;J)J
    at com.apple.laf.ScreenMenu.addMenuListeners(Native Method)
    at com.apple.laf.ScreenMenu.addNotify(ScreenMenu.java:254)
    at java.awt.Menu.addNotify(Menu.java:183)
    at com.apple.laf.ScreenMenu.addNotify(ScreenMenu.java:234)
    at com.apple.laf.ScreenMenuBar.add(ScreenMenuBar.java:285)
    at com.apple.laf.ScreenMenuBar.addSubmenu(ScreenMenuBar.java:223)
    at com.apple.laf.ScreenMenuBar.addNotify(ScreenMenuBar.java:66)
    at java.awt.Frame.addNotify(Frame.java:483)
    at java.awt.Window.pack(Window.java:807)
    at com.jthink.songkong.ui.MainWindow.setupScreen(MainWindow.java:322)
    at com.jthink.songkong.cmdline.SongKong.guiStart(SongKong.java:1494)
    at com.jthink.songkong.cmdline.SongKong.finish(SongKong.java:1602)
    at com.jthink.songkong.cmdline.SongKong.main(SongKong.java:1627)
```

any ideas ?

Although the lib is opensrc it does not seem to be hosted on github, although the author has other libs on github

Comment: @AlanSnyder can you help

Comment: you have look at this issue of OpenJDK? https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8166683

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
I checked the website and it seems that the author for the website has extended support for macOS Catalina. I suggest you try downloading and using the LaF now.
[image: New snapshot from website]

I don't think the VAqua look and feel is supported on Catalina, but I maybe wrong about the source of the error. Below are screenshots from the [VAqua website](https://violetlib.org/vaqua/overview.html).

[image: Old snapshot from website]

[image]